# Yii left join query

Tags: sql, yii

I want to execute the below sql query using Yii framework and need help on this.

**SQL query**

```
SELECT t.*, LP.name AS lp_name FROM `user` AS `t` LEFT JOIN `level_profiles` AS `LP` ON t.prof_i = LP.id WHERE t.bld_i IN (17)
```

So, i tried the below steps.

```
$usql = 't.bld_i IN (17)';

$criteria1 = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria1->select = 't.*, LP.*';
$criteria1->join = ' LEFT JOIN `level_profiles` AS `LP` ON t.prof_i = LP.id';
$criteria1->addCondition($usql);
$criteria1->order = 't.prof_i';

$result    =    User::model()->findAll($criteria1);
```

The above step is not allowing me to access the value from 'level_profiles' table.

Then, i tried to execute:

```
$usql = 't.bld_i IN (17)';

$result = User::model()->with('level_profiles', array(
                'level_profiles'=>array(
                    'select'=>'name',
                    'joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN',
                    'condition'=>'level_profiles.id="prof_i"',
                ),
            ))->findAll($usql);
```

This is returning an error 'Relation "level_profiles" is not defined in active record class "User". '

I know this could be executed using the below method.

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT query')->queryAll();
```

But i dont want to use the above.

I am a beginner with Yii and tried to look into the forums. But, i am getting confused how to execute the query using "User::model()" approach .

Comment: did you declare relations in your User model?

Comment: sorry, i am not aware of how to declare the relations. can you please provide some details how to do so?

Comment: check this article http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{
    ......

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'level_porfile_relation'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Level_Profiles_Modelname', 'prof_i'),

        );
    }
```

and your query will be:

```
$result = User::model()->with('level_porfile_relation')->findAll($usql);
```